# Can't display text in Libgdx

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I'm making an android game using Libgdx. I'm pretty new to this and I can't find out, why my text in the command font.draw() is not displaying.
All was working until the time I added a stage to this game. I also have upper in the code order sb.begin();

I was googling a lot and I swear I spent at least 4 hours googling, but it was all unsuccessful.

If anybody can help me I would be really greatful.

Thank you so much for any reply!

```
        sb.draw(gameoverImg, cam.position.x - gameoverImg.getWidth() / 2, cam.position.y + 95);
        sb.draw(table, cam.position.x - table.getWidth() / 2 + 33, cam.position.y - 180);


        font.getData().setScale(0.25f);
        font.draw(sb, "" + currentHighScore, cam.position.x + 30, FlappyDemo2.HEIGHT / 2 - 200);
        font.draw(sb, "" + score, cam.position.x + 30, FlappyDemo2.HEIGHT / 2 - 159);




        myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(playBtn2);
        myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
        button = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
        button.setPosition(253/2, 112);
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport()); //Set up a stage for the ui
        stage.addActor(button); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.


        myTextureRegion2 = new TextureRegion(scoreBtn);
        myTexRegionDrawable2 = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion2);
        button2 = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable2); //Set the button up
        button2.setPosition(345, 185);
        stage.addActor(button2);
```

Comment: How about `stage.addActor(font);` ?

Comment: Your code is a mess. Is that the update method and are you initializing a new stage every frame? That is not a good idea, start with 100 hours of basic programming lessons/books/tutorials and leave game programming for now. Apart from that, to answer your question we need to know where and how the `SpriteBatch` is setup and the size and position of the `Viewport` or `Camera` you are having. It might be drawn outside the screen or too small. Also make sure that `String` is not empty.

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved it by creating a label and then I used stage.addActor(label);

Comment: @OndřejŠerek I do not think you "really" solved it. I answered your question, i suggest you follow it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about programming start with the basics. If that is your update method then you are creating a `new Stage` and 2 `new ImageButton` and loading textures each frame. If you think about that for a second you realize that is the wrong way to do it. Using the new keyword is "expensive" since it creates a new object. On our fast computers this does not matter too much but eventually you will create lag. Also, if you create a new Stage every frame you cannot really do much with it since well... the old one gets disposed every time. You could do this outside the update loop.

If that is not your update method then move the lines where you draw to the update method. Also make sure the update method clears the screen every frame. This is how graphics usually work, each frame the screen is cleared and everything gets redrawn.

I strongly advice you to leave game programming and start with basic java tutorials. This will make your life a lot easier since at the moment you are drowning and will be for a while if you don't take this step by step. I do want to point you into the right direction and hopefully the following code is an eye opener. The most important part of programming is to work neat and structure your code. A method longer then 10 lines can be split up into multiple methods and will be way more readable.

I always use the Screen functionality build into LibGDX to start off.

TestScreen.java

```
/**
 * Extending from screen adapter to gain it's functionality and implement the Gesture Listener to use input.
 */
public class TestScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {

    // Declare fields, here we reserve memory to put the objects in.
    // There is almost never a reason to make your fields public.
    // Expose them with getters and setters if you need too.
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private Stage stage;

    private BitmapFont font;

    /**
     * The constructor gets run whenever you use the new keyword.
     * This is a good place to initialize the fields.
     */
    public TestScreen() {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

        // There are many viewports, this just sets the viewport to the size of the window width and
        // height. Note that most, if not all other viewports ask for worldWidth and worldHeight not
        // screenWidth and screenHeight.
        // It is also important to note that at this point when the code runs the window is not opened
        // yet so the viewport does not get any width. That is why we need to update it in the resize
        // method below, this will also make sure it does it's job when stretching the window.
        viewport = new ScreenViewport();
        viewport.apply();

        // Never load assets and textures in the game loop. Unless of course you let the player load
        // a image but then just load it once and not every frame.
        // I used a random font in my library with the size of 20 pixels.
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/sarpanch_20.fnt"));


        // I put the stage setup in it's own method.
        stage = new Stage();
        setupStage();

        // Input multiplexer allows for multiple input sources. In this case we made this screen
        // a GestureListener and the stage also needs input if you want to press buttons.
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(
            new GestureDetector(this),
            stage
        ));
    }

    /**
     * This is already a fairly long method. I could have put the click listener in it's own method
     * so we could reuse it on other actors and the code will be more readable.
     */
    private void setupStage() {
        // Use clear instead of the new keyword whenever you can.
        stage.clear();

        // I advice to use the Skin functionality for actor elements. It works great when you know
        // what you are doing. For now, just a style object.
        Label.LabelStyle style = new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.RED);

        // final makes sure you won't put a new object in the field. It is needed because I use it
        // in the listener/observer pattern below and that only runs when it observers a specific
        // event. Thus it needs to still be the same object.
        final Label label = new Label("Hello World", style);
        label.setPosition(100, 100);

        // Add awesome effect to label.
        label.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                label.getStyle().fontColor = Color.BLUE;
            }

            @Override
            public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                label.getStyle().fontColor = Color.RED;
            }
        });
        // Instead I could have moved this click listener to addHoverColor(Actor actor)... 
        // sure, the above code would remain similar but in here it would read.
        // addHoverColor(label);
        // Which is much more readable.

        // add the Label actor to stage.
        stage.addActor(label);
    }

    /**
     * render is the game loop. delta is the time since previous frame.
     * @param delta
     */
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);

        // Unfortunately LibgDX couples logic and drawing in this method.
        // Always remember to do the logic first and then render
        // Let's make 2 methods for that to keep the code neat and decoupled.
        update(delta);
        draw();

        //I use Stage to draw my GUI, the logic goes in update but the gui is always drawn on top
        drawGui();
    }


    private void update(float delta) {
        stage.act();
    }

    private void draw() {
        //Clear screen and fill it with color.
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.05f, .05f, .05f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // I want to be able to move the camera around so the sprite batch needs to know it projection
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);

        spriteBatch.setColor(Color.RED);

        spriteBatch.begin();
        //Use the SpriteBatch to draw the font.
        font.draw(spriteBatch, "Hello World", 100, 100);
        spriteBatch.end();

        //System.out.println(viewport.getCamera().viewportWidth);

    }

    private void drawGui() {
        stage.draw();
    }

    /**
     * resize is called whenever the window changes size. So also at the start when the window is
     * being set to your or default config size.
     * @param width
     * @param height
     */
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }

    // Screen adapter also has pause(), resume() and dispose(). But I leave those for now.


    // Following the mandatory methods from the GestureListener. I just use pan to move the camera around
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        viewport.getCamera().translate(-deltaX, deltaY, 0);
        viewport.getCamera().update();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void pinchStop() {

    }
}
```

Now we just need a minor change in the main core class.

```
// Extend from game instead of application listener
public class MyGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create () {
        // Now you have access to setScreen.
        setScreen(new TestScreen());
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense. It is short and simple, I'm sure you can read my code while I am having trouble reading yours. So let me press again, writing neat code is the most important aspect of programming. Not just for us but for yourself too. Obviously having a solid basic knowledge of the language helps with that.